# sklearn Linear Regression vs Batch Gradient Descent

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression

tldr: Why would sklearn LinearRegression give a different result than gradient descent?

My understanding is that LinearRegression is computing the closed form solution for linear regression (described well here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278755/why-use-gradient-descent-for-linear-regression-when-a-closed-form-math-solution). LinearRegression is not good if the data set is large, in which case stochastic gradient descent needs to be used. I have a small data set and wanted to use Batch Gradient Descent (self written) as an intermediate step for my own edification.

**I get different regression weights using LinearRegression and Batch Gradient Descent. Shouldn't the solution be unique?**

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv(r'') #Data set attached
X=data[['Size','Floor','Broadband  Rate']]
y=data['Rental Price']

#Sklearn Linear Regression
ols=linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)
LR=ols.fit(X,y)
Res_LR=y.values-LR.predict(X) #Residuals 
print('Intercept', LR.intercept_, 'Weights', LR.coef_)

#Batch Gradient Descent
def error_delta(x,y,p,wn):
    total=0
    row,column=np.shape(x)
    
    for i in range(0,row):
        if wn!=0:total+=(y[i]-(p[0]+np.dot(p[1:len(p)],x[i,:])))*x[i,wn-1]
        else: total+=(y[i]-(p[0]+np.dot(p[1:len(p)],x[i,:])))*1    
    return total

def weight_update(x,y,p,alpha):
    old=p
    new=np.zeros(len(p))
    for i in range(0,len(p)): new[i]=old[i]+alpha*error_delta(x,y,old,i)
    return new

weight=[-.146,.185,-.044,.119] #random starting conditions
alpha=.00000002 #learning rate

for i in range(0,500): #Seems to have converged by 100
    weight=weight_update(X.values,y.values,weight,alpha)

Res_BGD=np.zeros(len(X.values))
for i in range(0,len(X.values)): Res_BGD[i]=y.values[i]-(weight[0]+np.dot(weight[1::],X.values[i,:]))

print('Inercept', weight[0], 'Weights', weight[1:len(weight)]) 

plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(X.values)),Res_LR,color='b')
plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(X.values)), Res_BGD,color='g')
plt.legend(['Res LR', 'Res BGD'])
plt.show()
```

The data set is below (10 points)

```
Size,Floor,Broadband  Rate,Energy Rating,Rental Price
"  500   ","    4    ","    8    ","    C ","   320 "
"  550   ","    7    ","    50   ","    A ","   380 "
"  620   ","    9    ","    7    ","    A ","   400 "
"  630   ","    5    ","    24   ","    B ","   390 "
"  665   ","    8    ","    100  ","    C ","   385 "
"  700   ","    4    ","    8    ","    B ","   410 "
"  770   ","    10   ","    7    ","    B ","   480 "
"  880   ","    12   ","    50   ","    A ","   600 "
"  920   ","    14   ","    8    ","    C ","   570 "
"  1000  ","    9    ","    24   ","    B ","   620 "
```

When you plot the residuals, the performance is comparable despite very different weights

> SklearnLR Intercept 19.5615588974
> Weights [ 0.54873985  4.96354677 -0.06209515]
>
> BGD Inercept -0.145402077197
> Weights [ 0.62549182 -0.0344091   0.11473203]

Thoughts? Also, if there's any programming feedback, I'm open to more efficient ways to code this as well.

Comment: Is there specific reason you don't normalize the data? That really helps with the convergence of the gradient descent.

Comment: Not a specific reason. It's an example from a book I'm using and I wanted to compare the results. I figured since the data set is small that it would be okay.

Also, the batch gradient descent results do compare well with the example from my book... it's that the built in sklearn LinearRegression gives significantly different results